# Occured org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException for existed class in my Spring project

Tags: spring, spring-security

I try to implement oauth 2.0 into Spring 3 hibernate project. 
I can not get rid of BeanCreationException. I could not find the cause for a while. There exists the class which log complaints 
Could you plz tell me what am i missing? regards
Can be accessed source of project through [github](https://github.com/webyildirim/trafikhaberci) link

Here is my security-configuration.xml
    
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2.xsd

```
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="roleHierarchy"
          class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
        <property name="hierarchy">
            <value>
                ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER
                ROLE_USER > ROLE_GUEST
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="roleVoter" class="com.trafficalarm.rest.security.HierarchicalJsr250Voter">
        <constructor-arg ref="roleHierarchy" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Access voters -->
    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <property name="decisionVoters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="roleVoter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <sec:global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"/>

    <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler"/>

    <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler"/>

</beans>
```

Here is pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <groupId>trafficalarm</groupId>
    <artifactId>trafficalarm</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.179</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- hibarnate  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency-->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- restfull -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency><dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>



        <!-- MySQL database driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSON Processing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- servlet-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is the complained of class:

```
package com.trafficalarm.rest.security;

import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.security.access.ConfigAttribute;
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Jsr250SecurityConfig;
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Jsr250Voter;
import org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchy;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
//import org.springframework.util.Assert;
/**
 * Created by iainporter on 14/10/2014.
 */

public class HierarchicalJsr250Voter extends Jsr250Voter {


    private RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy = null;

    public HierarchicalJsr250Voter(RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy) {
        this.roleHierarchy = roleHierarchy;
    }

    @Override
    public int vote(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> definition) {
        boolean jsr250AttributeFound = false;

        for (ConfigAttribute attribute : definition) {
            if (Jsr250SecurityConfig.PERMIT_ALL_ATTRIBUTE.equals(attribute)) {
                return ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }

            if (Jsr250SecurityConfig.DENY_ALL_ATTRIBUTE.equals(attribute)) {
                return ACCESS_DENIED;
            }

            if (supports(attribute)) {
                jsr250AttributeFound = true;
                // Attempt to find a matching granted authority
                for (GrantedAuthority authority : extractAuthorities(authentication)) {
                    if (attribute.getAttribute().equals(authority.getAuthority())) {
                        return ACCESS_GRANTED;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return jsr250AttributeFound ? ACCESS_DENIED : ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
    }

    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> extractAuthorities(Authentication authentication) {
        return roleHierarchy.getReachableGrantedAuthorities(authentication.getAuthorities());
    }
}
```

Here is the log:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [spring/business-config.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.trafficalarm.rest.security.HierarchicalJsr250Voter] for bean with name 'roleVoter' defined in class path resource [spring/security/security-configuration.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.trafficalarm.rest.security.HierarchicalJsr250Voter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4760)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5184)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1686)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.trafficalarm.rest.security.HierarchicalJsr250Voter] for bean with name 'roleVoter' defined in class path resource [spring/security/security-configuration.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.trafficalarm.rest.security.HierarchicalJsr250Voter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1327)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:385)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:362)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:348)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:283)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.findEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:142)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.setBeanFactory(JpaTransactionManager.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1540)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.trafficalarm.rest.security.HierarchicalJsr250Voter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1324)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:247)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:395)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1348)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1319)
    ... 35 more

Mar 18, 2015 4:24:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Mar 18, 2015 4:24:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/trafficalarm] startup failed due to previous errors
Mar 18, 2015 4:24:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Mar 18, 2015 4:24:19 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
WARNING: The web application [/trafficalarm] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Mar 18, 2015 4:24:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor F:\yildirimBck\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.0.RELEASE\base-instance\conf\Catalina\localhost\trafficalarm.xml has finished in 15,297 ms
Mar 18, 2015 4:24:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory F:\yildirimBck\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.0.RELEASE\base-instance\webapps\manager
Mar 18, 2015 4:24:19 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 18, 2015 4:24:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory F:\yildirimBck\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.0.RELEASE\base-instance\webapps\manager has finished in 359 ms
Mar 18, 2015 4:24:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory F:\yildirimBck\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.0.RELEASE\base-instance\webapps\ROOT
Mar 18, 2015 4:24:20 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 18, 2015 4:24:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory F:\yildirimBck\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.0.RELEASE\base-instance\webapps\ROOT has finished in 275 ms
Mar 18, 2015 4:24:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 18, 2015 4:24:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 15977 ms
```

Comment: com.trafficalarm.rest.security.HierarchicalJsr250Voter is missing or not loaded by your jvm

Comment: But, as i noted im sure that it is already existed under right package

Comment: Which development ide you are using?
It seems classes are not landing into your application server web-inf/classes, see if you have configured  build path properly, and required components are scanned through your spring config files, for me it was resolved but it seems project has other issues as well which you might need to look at after resolving this one.

Comment: I use sts eclipse. Project has some js issues, but it is not related with that. I am interested in this bean issue

Comment: I'm using eclipse, I found that there were build path errors due to properties folders configuration, I removed that from build configuration and exception went away.

Comment: Could you deploy my project on Tomcat successfully?

Comment: are you able to resolve exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.trafficalarm.rest.security.HierarchicalJsr250Voter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73422/discussion-between-user3247727-and-webyildirim).

Comment: I could not catch you in chat sorry. i still can not find the problem here. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The essential problem was the build path problem. When i moved security-configuration.xml file content into business-config.xml, ide(eclipse sts) warned me about build path problem. So i checked the build path of project, maven dependecies seem to be unchecked. I had changed version of JDK previously, so i think that caused this unchecked situation.